# iOS 7 YouTube HTML suddenly shows options on tap

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, youtube

I have several apps in the App Store that load YouTube videos with a UIWebView with the following HTML:

```
(NSString *)embedYoutubeUrl:(NSString *)url with:(int)width height:(int)height 
{
NSMutableString *html = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
[html appendString:@"<html><head>"];
[html appendString:@"<style type=\"text/css\">"];
[html appendString:@"body {"];
[html appendString:@"background-color: transparent;"];
[html appendString:@"color: white;"];
[html appendString:@"}"];
[html appendString:@"</style>"];
[html appendString:@"</head><body style=\"margin:0\">"];
[html appendFormat:@"<embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\"", url];
[html appendFormat:@"width=\"%0.0d\" height=\"%0.0d\"></embed>", width, height];
[html appendString:@"</body></html>"];
return html;
}
```

It was working fine up until the other day when it was pointed out to me that suddenly (without any code changes) when a user goes to start the video that a list of options shows up for a couple seconds before the video plays and following the video finishing playback (see screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/ux5qyuc3szjtryj/photo.PNG).

Has anyone else experienced this and found a solution to getting rid of it?